# Oracle UCM RIDC service get folder path using GET_SEARCH_RESULTS

Tags: java, oracle-ucm

I am using **GET_SEARCH_RESULTS** ridc calls to perform file search. I need to get folder information of that file being retrieved with result. Tried **DOC_INFO** also but I didn't get folder name / path information

Comment: Are you using Folders_g or FrameworkFolders?

Answer (score 0):

Answering with the assumption that you are using FrameworkFolders:
The DOC_INFO service will give you the path to the containing folder. It is in the local property `fParentPath`. If it isn't there, something is wrong.